# GraphQL - passing an ObjectType a parameter

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, graphql-js

I'm using `GraphQL` and it's working great, however, I can't seem to figure out how to pass a parameter into the `fields` section of my `Event GraphQLObjectType`.

I would like to be able to pass in the `currentUserId` (which is given to me through a token) into the `Event GraphQLObjectType` so I can add in an `isAttending` attribute.

I've attached code with comments of what I'm basically trying to do:

```
const Event = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Event',
  description: 'This represents an Event',
  fields: (currentUserId) => { // currentUserId is the parameter I would like to pass in 
    return {
      id: {
        type: GraphQLInt,
        resolve (event) {
          return event.id;
        }
      },
      title: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve (event) {
          return event.title;
        }
      },
      attendees: {
        type: new GraphQLList(User),
        resolve (event) {
          return event.getAttendees()
        }
      },
      // this is what I would like to do
      isAttending: {
        type: GraphQLBool,
        resolve (event) {
          return event.getAttendees({
            where: {
              id: currentUserId // that's the parameter I would like pass in
            }
          }).then(attendee => {
            return (attendee.length > 0 ? true : false);
          )};
        }
      }
      // end of what I'm trying to do //
    };
  }
});

const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  description: 'Root query object',
  fields: () => {
    return {
      events: {
        type: new GraphQLList(Event),
        args: {
          id: {
            type: GraphQLInt
          }
        },
        resolve (root, args) {
          // here is the parameter I would like to pass to the event object
          let currentUserId = root.userId; 
          ////////

          return Db.models.event.findAll({ where: args });
        }
      },
      ...
```

### Update

The reason I can't just do `data.currentUserId = root.userId`, is because it's not visible when I'm returned a `collection of event objects`, since what is passed into my `Event GraphQLOBjectType` is only the `{event}` object.

What it looks like when I do `data.currentUserId` and there is an array of objects inside `data` is this:

```
[{objects}, currentUserId: 1]
```

As opposed to what we want which is this:

```
[{object, currentUserId: 1}, {anotherObject, currentUserId: 1}]
```

If I wanted to have access to the `currentUserId` in the `Event GraphQLObject`, the only thing I can think of is to loop through every object and add the currentUserId onto it like this:

```
return events.map(event => { 
  event.currentUserId = currentUserId; 
  return event; 
});`
```

Is this the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that. `fields` doesn't recieve any parameters, so you won't send any either.

Fortunately, you can achieve that in more convenient way.

Everything your parent type (`Query`) returns in `resolve` function is visible in child resolve's `root` parameter.

```
const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    description: 'Root query object',
    fields: () => ({
            events: {
                type: new GraphQLList(Event),
                args: {
                    id: {
                        type: GraphQLInt
                    }
                },
                resolve (root, args) {

                    return Db.models.event.findAll({ where: args })
                            .then(data => {
                                // pass the parameter here
                                data.currentUserId = root.userId;
                                return data;
                            });
                }
            },
            ...
```

Then your `Event` object would look like this:

```
const Event = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Event',
    description: 'This represents an Event',
    fields: () => ({

        ...

        isAttending: {
            type: GraphQLBool,
            resolve: (event) => {
                return event.getAttendees({
                    where: {
                        id: event.currentUserId // that's the parameter you've passed through parent resolve
                    }
                }).then(attendee => {
                    return (attendee.length > 0 ? true : false);
                });
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Hey can you check out my update to the question? I tried your solution but had to change it up a little bit. Let me know what you think please @LordDave

Comment: It may seems ugly but I think it is the best and only solution. Since there is no other way how you can direct pass variables to children other than via resolve's root param, you have to extend all objects in your collection with this new variable.
Ideal solution would be pass it on Sequelize layer to the result, but unfortunately Sequelize can't do it

Comment: I think this is the best solution for now. I actually ran into the same problem and wrote an iterator which runs through the `fieldASTs` in the resolve function, fetches nested arguments and  allows for fields to be queried based on arguments. But this function is very messy and I'm embarrassed to show it publicly :(

You can actually have arguments for fields already, but only for manipulating results after fetching, i.e. padding a single digit number with 0.

Comment: This seems to be an ongoing debate in GraphQL. Facebook themselves apparently deal with it by having all queries start from a `viewer` node which has the current user information.